# Access other parts of state in Redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using Redux and would like to set a flag in the state if the user has modified data.

First I am hydrating my store with some data from the server:

```
let serverData = {toggle: true}
const store = configureStore({data: serverData, originalData: serverData})
```

I then have a few reducers:

```
function data(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
      return {
        ...state,
        toggle: !state.toggle
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function changed(state = false, action) {
  // This doesn't work; we are actually comparing state.changed.originalData and state.changed.data
  return isEqual(state.originalData, state.data)
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  data,
  originalData: (state={}) => state,
  changed
})
```

What I'd like to do here is set the `changed` flag to true if `state.data` no longer equals `state.originalData`. However, using combineReducers, I can't access these parts of the state inside my `changed` reducer.

What's the most idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do from the example, but it seems to me like you're using `combineReducers` for a task it wasn't meant to handle. That said, for a general comment on the problem, check out https://github.com/rackt/redux/issues/601#issuecomment-133519377

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that really helps me much unfortunately.

As a use case for me: I want to show a 'You have unsaved changes' notice when a user edits something on a page. If he then proceeds to put the content back into the original state, then this message should disappear. I'm struggling to do this with the Redux idiom of having each reducer view a separate piece of state; I need a reducer to compare two separate pieces of state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Michelle is right, to expand on it in traditional flux terms think of a reducer as a store, you just called one of your stores "data" and another "changed" - that's not semantic and shows you probably are confused about how they're used.

Your `changed` reducer is supposed to either return the unmodified state, or, if an action was made that it's interested in, return the *next* state. It isn't for figuring out if your store changed - that's what `subscribe` is for.

```
const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log('store was changed:', store.getState())
)
```

When you call `combineReducers` it will call each reducer once, with an action of `@@redux/INIT` -- but don't concern yourself with that as it's internal. The important thing to understand is that under each reducer key, the state is initialised. In your case you initialised `data` to an empty object, `changed` to false, and `originalData` to an empty object.

Next when you called `createStore` you said "Update the 'data' and 'originalData' stores with this initial state from the server". So now the state of the 'data' and 'serverData' stores are equal to `{toggle: true}`.

At this point both objects are the same.

Subsequently when you call `store.dispatch` all your reducers will be called so that they can have a chance to modify state (and return a new object) **under each reducer key**. Each reducer only has access to it's own state. Therefore in your `changed` reducer you can't check for the overall object equality of your entire state like that.

However you can check for object equality in the subscribe (mixed ES5/6 here for Chrome 47)

```
'use strict';

const serverData = {toggle: true};
const TOGGLE = 'TOGGLE';

function data(state, action) {
    state = state || {};
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
        toggle: !state.toggle
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function originalData(state) {
    state = state || {};
  return state;
}

const rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
  data,
  originalData
});

const store = Redux.createStore(rootReducer, {data: serverData, originalData: serverData });

const unsubscribe = store.subscribe(() =>
  console.log('on change equal?', store.getState().data === store.getState().originalData)
)

console.log('on load equal?', store.getState().data === store.getState().originalData);

store.dispatch({ type: TOGGLE });
```

The console.log output should be:

```
on load equal? true
on change equal? false
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/5nwfqo9k/1/

Comment: The guys is asking, is clear in the question. How can a reducer, access to another state data? Try to solve the problem, but then try to answer the question... "Access other parts of state in Redux reducer"